# Compare Value to Category Title In Template

Tags: templating

I'm new to Craft and am trying to set up a condition that will compare the value of a category (entry.position).  However, I get this error message:

```
Object of class Craft\ElementCriteriaModel could not be converted to string
```

I'm not really sure how to do a textual comparison.  The 'position' field is, in my case, a category.  How would a comparison be achieved?

I've tried this:

```
{% set entry_pos = entry.position %}
{#   {%  craft.categories.slug('position') %} #}                 
{{ entry_pos }}

{% if entry.position != 'staff' %}
    {% if entry.UBFUserName != '' %}
        {% set name_var = entry.UBFUserName %}
            {{ craft.aitest.AiTestVariable(name_var) }}
        {% else %}
    {% endif %}      
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `entry_pos` is an [Element Criteria Model](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/templating/elementcriteriamodel.html). You want to get the first (and probably only) category from this ElementCriteriaModel, and then compare its title to `'staff'`:

```
{% set entry_pos = entry.position.first %}
{% if entry_pos.title == 'staff' %}
  ...
{% endif %}
```

This will give you an error if there is no `entry.position.first`, as `entry_pos` will be `null`, so you should defend against that somehow. One possility is:

```
{% if entry_pos and entry_pos.title == 'staff' %} ...
```

Another is to use twigs useful [null-coalescing operator](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#other-operators):

```
{% if (entry_pos.title ?? '') == 'staff' %} ...
```

With Craft 3, you will use `one` instead of `first`, but otherwise everything is the same.

Comment: Would parentheses be needed in the compound conditional statement (above)?  For some reason, the if/then statement is returning 'yes' to both 'staff' and 'faculty'.

Comment: I'm not sure if the ()'s are needed - depends on twig operator precedence.

Comment: Thanks.  That did the job - I added 'lower' to it to fix the remainder of the problem.  {% if entry_pos and (entry_pos.title|lower != 'staff') %}